# Can we beat the port restriction to a particular IP using multiple NAT boxes?

Tags: networking, home-networking, nat

Imagine 2 NAT boxes are used together we have 2 mappings of “src_port -> dst_port.” If they are used in series. “src_port1 -> dst_port1” and then “dst_port1 -> dstport2.”

Does having multiple nat boxes increase the connection limit it can serve?

Answer (score 4):

No, because the connections are just translated twice doesn't mean you have any more connections to play with.

A becomes B, and B becomes C - every time.

1000 connections to A, means 1000 connections to C.

Comment: Is there any other way we can increase the number of connections using 2 natboxes?

Comment: @AneeshDogra no, unless you can explain exactly what your problem is. Currently it's too vague. Number of connections to a single program? Well, if it could listen on two ports then you could use that I guess...